# Striped text in CSS

Tags: css

How can I make text to have a striped color with CSS?

Something like `background-image`or `background-color` applied to text. Or would I have to download a font that is coloured that way?

Comment: I have to ask why would you want to do something like that? unreadable and unfriendly

Comment: yes, it was not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LMg7q/2/

```
.striped{
    font-size: 128px;
    background-size: 16px;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    background-color: #AC0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

- [Great article on striped backgrounds](http://lea.verou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/)
- [Alternate method](http://jsfiddle.net/LMg7q/1/) using a background image (per OP's request)
- Note the use of `background-clip` and `background-size`

Comment: How can I put this http://www.stripegenerator.com/generators/generate_shared_stripe.php?stripe=1449 as background?, thanks

Comment: @juanpastas Chrome isn't the only browser out there.  Anyone not using a Webkit browser just sees the gradient and no text at all.

Comment: it works in Safari also... which others should I try to probe that works on webkit?

Comment: You should also try FF, IE 8-9

Comment: You could selectively apply the style based on feature-detection, and fallback to plain text for other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This works cross (modern) browser including IE.

I believe svg is what you are after:

http://jsdo.it/Raam.Danger.Rosh-Hai/t93l

[image: Striped text]

```
<svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400">
  <desc>Example textdecoration01 - behavior of 'text-decoration' property</desc>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398" fill="pink"  stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
  <g font-size="220"  fill="url(#img2)" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" >
    <text x="100" class="text" y="205">Normal text</text>
   <defs>
    <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="http://price.sourceforge.net/manual/images/vert_stripes.gif" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="130" />

    </pattern>

</defs>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can use an image for a `pattern` in SVG.

```
 xlink:href="http://price.sourceforge.net/manual/images/vert_stripes.gif"
```

Is the link to the picture.

just change it to what ever you wish.

the `width` and `height` that follow it control the size of the image being duplicated.

have fun.
    ​

Comment: Cool idea, although it's worth noting that this doesn't appear to work at all in IE8 so you are still stuck providing a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to wrap each single character in a span element and apply a color to the span - than each character has it's own color.

```
<span style="color:red">H</span>
<span style="color:blue">O</span>
<span style="color:green">I</span>
```

This will work in any browser - but it's a hell to maintain or if you need to change the text.

Answer (score 1):

see the **[demo](http://jsbin.com/ahisej/1/edit)**

```
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.03, rgb(250,3,3)),
    color-stop(0.52, rgb(240,255,127)),
    color-stop(0.76, rgb(42,24,173)));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This is obviously webkit-dependent, though. Don't expect this to work on Firefox, Opera or IE.

Comment: @Joost - you could make it work in firefox and opera if you used their vendor prefixes - but still IE will fail yes.

Comment: True. I was just adding the remark as an assurance for any readers using a non-webkit browser that found the demo to be non-functional ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the implementation examples. Code can be found here if you want to play with it online:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEmgbB?editors=1000

[image: SVG Striped Text]

```
<svg  width="188" height="32" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs> 
    <pattern id="style-stripes" width="90" height="64" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <line x1="0" y1="0"   x2="90"  y2="0"  style="stroke: #E03A3E; stroke-width:8;" />
      <line x1="0" y1="8"  x2="90"  y2="8" style="stroke: #963D97; stroke-width:8;" />
      <line x1="0" y1="16"  x2="90"  y2="16" style="stroke: #009DDC; stroke-width:8;" />
      <line x1="0" y1="24"   x2="90"  y2="24"  style="stroke: #61BB46; stroke-width:8;" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g fill="url(#style-stripes)" stroke="none" font-size="32" font-family="serif">
    <text x="0" y="24" style="fill:#333;fill-opacity:1;">Reactive</text>
    <text x="120" y="24">Style</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```